# Get number in properties as String (java.util.Properties, Android)

Tags: java, android, properties

I have a property

```
text=000.01
```

but using *java.util.Properties*'s method

```
getProperty("text");
```

returns **"0.01"** *(must be "000.01")*

P.S. Methods:

```
get("text").toString();
```

returns **"0.01"** too.

P.S.S Take into account this is Android code.

---

#### *some time later*

The `Properties#getProperty` method works fine. The problem was in my incorrect definition of column in SQLite db. I declared column as `integer` which worked fine with `String` data. So when I stored "some string" I din't get any problem and forgot about integer type.

> One of the biggest differences between hobbyists and professional programmers
> is the difference that grows out of moving from superstition into understanding.
> The word “superstition” in this context doesn’t refer to a program that gives you
> the creeps or generates extra errors when the moon is full. It means substituting
> feelings about the code for understanding. If you often find yourself suspecting
> that the compiler or the hardware made an error, you’re still in the realm of
> superstition. Only about 5 percent of all errors are hardware, compiler, or
> operating-system errors (Ostrand and Weyuker 1984). Programmers who have
> moved into the realm of understanding always suspect their own work first
> because they know that they cause 95 percent of errors. Understand the role of
> each line of code and why it’s needed. Nothing is ever right just because it seems
> to work. If you don’t know why it works, it probably doesn’t—you just don’t
> know it yet.
> **Steve McConnell (Code Complete)**

Comment: That sounds unlikely. Where exactly have you got that property? In a .properties file?

Comment: Yes. I have a file with properties that I load to Properties instance  as it is.

Comment: Then it should already return "000.01" if that's the text in the properties file. I suspect you don't have the file you think you have, or your diagnostics are off.

Comment: I write a file by myself (for testing). When I write `text=01ASD` I receive _"O1ASD"_ too, but in case with 000.01 I got unnecessary intelligence answer.

Comment: How are you displaying the result? Perhaps it's your IDE which is trying to be intelligent for you?

Comment: Yes! You are right, the problem was in my "intelligent" data transferring. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`getProperty()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) method always return `String` that doesn't know 000.01 = 0.01 in maths context. So this shouldn't happen.

Comment: may be you are looking at wrong file. please do search in your ide set file name pattern = "*.properties" and key ="0.01" , it will open up the things

Comment: Multiple tabs open copied wrong one.. changed it. as far as I know android runs on jdk 1.5

Comment: even you can refer [this link](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/2.3/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty(java.lang.String))

Comment: As I wrote above, there are no errors in the file. Now I'm rechecking code (again :) ).

Comment: I found my problem. Sorry for trouble. It was just panic attack. :)